# javascript sort in wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble with a javascript (node.js) sort function not sorting things in the correct order all the time. I need it to sort through negative and positive numbers and return the smallest non-negative number first. This is what I'm using right now:

```
.sort(function(a, b){if(a >= 0){return a - b;}else{return 1;}});
```

But when there is only one positive number, and it's at the end which happens often, that number is sorted as second to last. Can I have some help with a better way to implement this?

Comment: Can you give us example array that does not work? It looks fine to me. `[-3,-6,-4,1].sort(function(a, b){if(a >= 0){return a - b;}else{return 1;}})` returns `[1, -4, -6, -3]` Smallest positive is always first.

Comment: Just pass this to your function `sort` `function(a,b) { return a - b;} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
alert([8,5,-1,-8,-2,7,1,10,1,7,-3].sort(function(a,b) {
  return a*b < 0 ? b : a-b;
}));
```

The ternary operator is a shortcut for `if ... else`, so the above is equivalent to writing:

```js
alert([8,5,-1,-8,-2,7,1,10,1,7,-3].sort(function(a,b) {
  if(a*b < 0) return b;
  else return a-b;
}));
```

This code returns true if `a` and `b` have different signs (positive and negative):

```
if(a*b < 0) return b;
```

If `b` is positive, `sort` places it *before* the negative `a`.  If `b` is negative, `sort` places it *after* the positive `a`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not exactly sure how this works and Pluto's doesn't, but I'm going to go read up on the ternary operator now. Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Pluto's method also works.  You can see its output in the console.  I've updated my answer with more explanation of how my method works.

Answer (score 2):

This sorting function works because it only sorts numbers if `a` is on the same side of 0 as `b` is:

```
function SortNonNegativesFirst(a,b){
    if((a>=0) == (b>=0)) // Checks if both numbers are on the same side of zero
        return a-b;
    return a<b; // One is negative, one is positive, so return whether a is negative
}
console.log([1,6,8,4,-3,5,-2,3].sort(SortNonNegativesFirst)); //[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, -3, -2]
```